# Google Forms to PDF to Email

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-docs, google-forms, export-to-pdf

I am creating an online process for our employees to submit a leave of absence form. I have a google sheet collecting responses to a leave of absence google form. I want to take responses from the google sheet, autofill them into a temp doc based on a google doc template, make the autofilled form into a pdf and then automatically email that pdf to an email (the submitters supervisor- which is a question on the google form). I would like to then delete the temp autofilled doc and only keep the pdf version in my drive. The script I am using is not working though. For anything. My code is below.

The errors I have been getting is that `e` is `undefined`, `0` is `undefined`, 'Name' is `undefined`. I have not been able to create any pdfs but some of the form response are being filled into the temp google doc template. Can you please help me figure out how to make this script work?

```
function AfterFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log("e:  " + JSON.stringify(e));
  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
  const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LOA Form Responses");
  ws.getRange(entryRow, 25).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
  
  sendEmail(e.namedValues['Supervisor Email'][0].pdfFile);  
}


function sendEmail(email){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "New LOA Request", "Please review the LOA Request form attached and either approve or deny.",{
    attachments: [pdfFile],  name: "Harmonium LOA"})    
}

function createPDF(info)
{ 
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1sfGo81QTb012oCI0PUPUmfQaLRh3PZcG")
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1b5hjRebTofFZc907O8HZX8l4hrAlLC-G")
  const templateDoc =  DriveApp.getFileById("1iS6JKlPgHfQd18_NTBJEsW7A0OwSxpZW7SM9HQhpZkg")
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Name}", info['Name'][0]); 
  body.replaceText("{Timestamp}", info['Timestamp'][0]); 
  body.replaceText("{Site/Dept.}", info['Location'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Adress}", info['Home Address'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{ID}", info['Employee ID'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Title}", info['Title'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Leave}", info['Leave Type'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{PersonalReason}", info['Reason'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{FMLA/CFRAReason}", info['Reason'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{COVIDReason}", info['Reason'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Birth/Adoption/Placement}", info['Due date, adoption date or placement date of child.'][0]); 
  body.replaceText("{Start Date}", info['Start Date'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Return Date}", info['Anticipated Return Date'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Request Type}", info['New or Existing Request'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Hours}", info['Hours'][0]);
  body.replaceText('{Cont / Inter}', info['Continuous or intermittent'][0]);
  body.replaceText('{Inter Schedule}', info['Intermittent work schedule'][0]);
  body.replaceText('{Birth/Adoption/Placement}', info['Due date, adoption date or placement date of child.'][0]);
  body.replaceText('{Documentation}', info['Documentation'][0]);
  body.replaceText('{Payment Plan}', info['Payback Plan'][0]);
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  
  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Name'][0] + " LOA-" + info['Start Date'][0]);
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
  return pdfFile;
}
```

Comment: Few clarifications :- 1: Did you set the installable trigger on Spreadsheet side, asking because you said, you're getting `e is undefined error`? 2: Are you able to successfully edit the template, without error? 3: why you're calling `createPDF()` again inside `sendEmail()` if you already got return from that function in `AfterFormSubmit()`?, Thanks

Comment: Consider that `getActiveSpreadsheet()` is related to the currently active user, therefore when nothing happens because a trigger is needed and the Spreadsheet needs to be explicitly defined.

Comment: I did set the installable trigger on Spreadsheet side. When I submit a new form nothing happens besides the responses appearing on the google sheet. It looks like the AfterFormSubmit section is not working within the first few lines. It is saying that TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined
AfterFormSubmit @ PDF.gs:3